# Publishing and subscribing through mqtt in Linux

Tags: mqtt, iot

After publishing the message if I subscribe with a new device, it does not receive the message immediately instead I have to publish the message again to recieve it. Why does that happen and how do I fix it?

For subscribing pc i put the command

```
mosquitto_sub -h publisher_ip -t topic_name
```

For publisher pc

```
mosquitto_pub -h publisher_ip -t topic_name -m message
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Pub/Sub messaging just doesn't work that way.

Under normal circumstances messages are only delivered to clients that are online and have a valid subscriptions that matches the topic the message was published on.

Pub/Sub messaging is not message queuing.

Now, there are 2 exceptions to this rule.

1. If messages is published with the retained bit set, then the last message published on each topic (with the bit set) will be held in the broker and delivered to any client that subsequently subscribes to the matching topic at the point they subscribe. They will also receive any new messages. You can read more about retained messages [here](https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-8-retained-messages/)

   Messages can be published with the retained bit by adding `-r` to the `mosquitto_pub` command
2. If a client with a fixed client id connects and subscribes to a bunch of topics with a QOS of greater than `0` then disconnects. If when they then reconnect, they use the same client id and ensure that the Clean Session flag is set to `false` when connecting, all the old subscriptions will be continued from the previous session and the broker will have queued any missed messages. This is called a Persistent Subscription, and you can read more [here](https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-7-persistent-session-queuing-messages/)

   ```
    mosquitto_sub -i some_client_id -q 1 -c -t topic_name
   ```

   - `-c` sets clean session to `false`
   - `-i some_client_id` sets the client id
   - `-q 1` sets the subscription QOS to 1

Answer (score -1):

It's always nice to see more folks interested in MQTT!

@hardillb is absolutely accurate here, @Parag.

With MQTT, when a message is published to a topic, it is delivered to all relevant subscribers to that topic at the time it is published.  If a client is offline or subscribes to a topic after the message has been sent, the message will not be received, as the message has already been sent and resolved by the broker.

Retained messages, as offered by @hardillb, are a way to specify a message for a topic (note that this is *topic* specific) to be delivered immediately when a client subscribes to that topic.

Full disclosure, as I am a member of the HiveMQ team, but I highly recommend the [MQTT essentials series](https://www.hivemq.com/mqtt-essentials/) that HiveMQ offers - this goes over the fundamentals of MQTT and can be a great resource for understanding the protocol as a whole.

Best,

Aaron from the HiveMQ Team